# How to change the color of a senders parent on event?

Tags: visual-studio, vba, basic

I'm new to this Visual Environment and having trouble figuring out how to change the color of a panel when a radio button inside of it is clicked.

Heres the code I tried.  The msg box works to report that its coming from Panel1, but I can not use that same code to change the color of Panel1.

```
Private Sub rad01yes_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rad01yes.CheckedChanged
    MsgBox(sender.parent.name.ToString(), vbOK, "TitleHere")
    sender.parent.name.colorselection = Color.Black
End Sub
```

and i've also tried

```
sender.parent.colorselection = Color.Black
```

And

```
    Dim myPanel As Panel = sender
    myPanel.BackColor = Color.Black
```

I can't find anything with a search.  I think I might be phrasing my question wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `sender` is of type `Object` and therefore has no `Parent` or `BackColor` property. Instead, you need to cast `Sender.Parent` to the type of `Panel` with `DirectCast`.

```
Private Sub rad01yes_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rad01yes.CheckedChanged
    MsgBox(sender.parent.name.ToString(), vbOK, "TitleHere")
    Dim sendersPanel = DirectCast(sender.Parent, Panel)
    sendersPanel.BackColor = Color.Black
End Sub
```

Be warned, however. The `CheckChanged` event fires when the form first loads, so the above code will cause the panel's color to be black when the program first starts up. You may want to code this in the `RadioButton`'s `Clicked` Event Handler, instead.

Comment: Or just set the radiobuttons handlers in the Form's New Method, after the InitializeComponent call, that way you will not get the method firing on Form Load